# return false if array exist in localstorage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, local-storage

```
var arr= new Array();

arr.push("John");

localStorage["name"] = JSON.stringify(arr);
```

How to check if John existed in the localstorage? What to do next after I got the values?

```
JSON.parse(localStorage["name"]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> return-false-if-array-exist-in-localstorage

```
JSON.parse(localStorage["name"]).indexOf("John") !== -1 ? false : true;
```

Comment: why use indexOf instead of $.each?

Comment: @AaronMusktin Why would `$.each()` be utilized ? See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Comment: @AaronMusktin You definitely wouldn't want to iterate through each value in the array unless there wasn't a built-in way to check this sort of thing.

Comment: @guest271314 FYI, you can shorten that to `JSON.parse(localStorage["name"]).indexOf("John") != -1` if you wanted. Though some may argue it's significantly less readable.

Comment: @guest271314 what if the value isn't an array but array object, can use indexOf too?

Comment: @AaronMusktin Question appear to reference `Array` "return false if array exist in localstorage?" ? `Array.prototype.indexOf` is method of `Array.prototype` , see link at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30542151/return-false-if-array-exist-in-localstorage/30542195?noredirect=1#comment49157587_30542195 .   Has original Question as to  "return false if array exist in localstorage?"  been resolved ?

Answer (score 2):

To **add** a value to `localStorage`, use the syntax

```
localStorage.setItem("key", "value");
```

To **retrieve** a value from `localStorage`, use the syntax

```
var data = localStorage.getItem("key");
```

Following your example, you would do something like

```
var arr = ['John'];
localStorage.setItem("name", JSON.stringify(arr));
```

And checking if the element 'John' exists in the array is trivial:

```
var arr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("name"));
if (arr.indexOf("John") == -1) { // Array.indexOf() returns -1 if element not found
    // Then "John" does not exist in the array
} else {
    // "John" exists in the array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JSON.parse( localStorage["name"] ).indexOf('John3')
```